# Order by fields from different tables create full table scan. Should I combine data to one table?

Tags: mysql, sql

This is a theoretical question. Sorry, but I don't have a working tables data to show, I'll try to improvise with a theoretical example.
Using MySql/MariaDB. Have indexes for all relevant fields.

I have a system, which historical design had a `ProductType` table, something like:

```
ID=1, Description="Milk"
ID=2, Description="Bread"
ID=3, Description="Salt"
ID=4, Description="Sugar"
```

and so on.

There are some features in the system that rely on the `ProductType` ID and the Description is also used in different places, such as for defining different properties of the product type.

There is also a `Product` table, with fields such as:

```
ID, ProductTypeID, Name
```

The `Product:Name` don't have the product type description in it, so a "Milk bottle 1l" will have an entry such as:

```
ID=101, ProductTypeID=1, Name="bottle 1l"
```

and "Sugar pack 1kg" will be:

```
ID=102, ProductTypeID=4, Name="pack 1kg"
```

You get the idea...

The system combines the `ProductType:Description` and Product:Name to show full product names to the users. This creates a systematic naming for all the products, so there is no way to define a product with a name such as "1l bottle of milk". I know that in English that might be hard to swallow, but that way works great with my local language.

Years passed, the database grow to millions of products.

Since full-text index should have all searched data in one table, I had to store the `ProductType:Description` inside the `Product` table in a string field I added that have different keywords related to the product, so the full-text search will be able to find anything related to the product (type, name, barcode, SKU and etc.)

Now I'm trying to solve the full table scans and it makes me think that current design might not be optimal and I'll have to redesign and store the full product name (type + name) in the same table...

In order to show the proper order of the products there's an `ORDER BY TypeDescription ASC, ProductName ASC` after the `ProductType` table is joined to `Product` select queries.
From my research I see that the database can't use indexes when the order is done on fields from different tables, so it's doing full table scan to get to the right entries.

During pagination, there's `ORDER` and `LIMIT 50000,100` in the query that take lots of time.
There are sections with lots for products, so that ordering and limiting cause very long full table scans.

How would you handle that situation?
Change the design and store all query related data to the Product table? Feels a bit of a duplication and not natural solution.
Or maybe there's another way to solve it?
Will index on VARCHAR type (product name) be efficient for the ORDER speed? Or the database will still do full table scan?

My first question here. Couldn't find answers on similar cases.
Thanks!

I've tried to play with the queries to see if ordering by a VARCHAR field that have an index will work, but the `EXPLAIN SELECT` still shows that the query didn't use the index and did WHERE run :(

**UPDATE**

Trying to add some more data...
The situation is a bit more complicated and after digging a bit more it looks like the initial question was not in the right direction.
I removed the product type from the queries and still have the slow query.
I feel like it's a chicken and egg situation...

I have a table that maps prodcut IDs to section IDs:

```
CREATE TABLE `Product2Section` (
  `SectionId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ProductId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  KEY `idx_ProductId` (`ProductId`),
  KEY `idx_SectionId` (`SectionId`),
  KEY `idx_ProductId_SectionId` (`ProductId`,`SectionId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC
```

The query (after stripping all non-relevant to the question feilds):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    DRIVER.ProductId AS ID,
    p.*
FROM
    Product2Section AS DRIVER
LEFT JOIN Product p ON
    (p.ID = DRIVER.ProductId)
WHERE
    DRIVER.SectionId IN(
544,545,546,548,550,551,552,553,554,555,556,557,558,559,560,561,562,563,564,566,567,568,570,571,572,573,574,575,1337,1343,1353,1358,1369,1385,1956,1957,1964,1973,1979,1980,1987,1988,1994,1999,2016,2020,576,577,578,579,580,582,586,587,589,590,591,593,596,597,598,604,605,606,608,609,612,613,614,615,617,619,620,621,622,624,625,626,627,628,629,630,632,634,635,637,639,640,642,643,644,645,647,648,651,656,659,660,661,662,663,665,667,669,670,672,674,675,677,683,684,689,690,691,695,726,728,729,730,731,734,736,741,742,743,745,746,749,752,758,761,762,763,764,768,769,771,772,773,774,775,776,777
    )
ORDER BY
    p.ProductName ASC
LIMIT 500900,100;
```

explain shows:

| **id** | **select_type** | **table** | **type** | **possible_keys** | **key** | **key_len** | **ref** | **rows** | **Extra** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | DRIVER | index | idx_SectionId | idx_ProductId_SectionId | 8 | NULL | 589966 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
| 1 | SIMPLE | p | eq_ref | PRIMARY,idx_ID | PRIMARY | 4 | 4project.DRIVER.ProductId | 1 | Using where |

I've tried to select from the products table and join the Product2Section in order to filter the results, but get the same results:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    p.ID,
    p.ProductName
FROM
    Product p
LEFT JOIN 
    Product2Section p2s ON (p.ID=p2s.ProductId)
WHERE
    p2s.SectionId IN(
544,545,546,548,550,551,552,553,554,555,556,557,558,559,560,561,562,563,564,566,567,568,570,571,572,573,574,575,1337,1343,1353,1358,1369,1385,1956,1957,1964,1973,1979,1980,1987,1988,1994,1999,2016,2020,576,577,578,579,580,582,586,587,589,590,591,593,596,597,598,604,605,606,608,609,612,613,614,615,617,619,620,621,622,624,625,626,627,628,629,630,632,634,635,637,639,640,642,643,644,645,647,648,651,656,659,660,661,662,663,665,667,669,670,672,674,675,677,683,684,689,690,691,695,726,728,729,730,731,734,736,741,742,743,745,746,749,752,758,761,762,763,764,768,769,771,772,773,774,775,776,777
    )
ORDER BY
    p.ProductName ASC
LIMIT 500900,
100;
```

explain:

| **id** | **select_type** | **table** | **type** | **possible_keys** | **key** | **key_len** | **ref** | **rows** | **Extra** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | p2s | index | idx_ProductId,idx_SectionId,idx_ProductId_SectionId | idx_ProductId_SectionId | 8 | NULL | 589966 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
| 1 | SIMPLE | p | eq_ref | PRIMARY,idx_ID | PRIMARY | 4 | 4project.p2s.ProductId | 1 | Using where |

Don't see a way out of that situation.

**MORE DATA**

```sql
SELECT TABLE_ROWS, AVG_ROW_LENGTH, DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH
FROM information_schema.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Product2Section';
```

| TABLE_ROWS | AVG_ROW_LENGTH | DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7,374 | 37 | 901120 |
| 589,821 | 41 | 75153408 (71.7 MB) |
| 7,331 | 40 | 901120 |
| 0 | 0 | 65536 |

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM(DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH)/POW(1024, 3), 2)
FROM information_schema.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'databasename';


ROUND(SUM(DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH)/POW(1024, 3), 2)  
4.27    

SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_buffer%';

innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size   134217728   
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown ON  
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now OFF 
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_pct 25  
innodb_buffer_pool_filename ib_buffer_pool  
innodb_buffer_pool_instances    4   
innodb_buffer_pool_load_abort   OFF 
innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup  ON  
innodb_buffer_pool_load_now OFF 
innodb_buffer_pool_size 3758096384
```

Comment: [Rick's RoTs](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/ricksrots) has some good hints and tips for paginating large result sets. Using LIMIT with large offsets is always wasteful! You state that you've _"tried to play with the queries"_, so I suggest you add a specific example to your question, instead of trying to deal in the abstract. Add the query, the explain output and any relevant DDL to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the link. That was a good read (again). I remember that site from few years back. I don't see how it's possible to implement his pagination proposal when you order the list by a ProductName for example. Setting next possible ID doesn't really help since you have to re-order the list to know what will be next ID *AFTER* the order

Comment: With that much for the buffer_pool, I hope you have at least 6GB of RAM.

Comment: After the last order on the current page.  Or fetch one extra row, just to see if there is even another page.  [_Pagination_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination)  And, yes, "remember where you left off" may not be possible due to the Join.

Comment: Sounds like 4 databases have a `Product2Section` table?  Which one is relevant?

Comment: Hmmm... I don't see where the Optimizer got rid of `DISTINCT`, or even if it did.  Please provide `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT...` (for one of the queries).  Meanwhile, note that the Optimizer picked `Product2Section` as the "first" table, regardless of the FROM/JOIN order.

Comment: On second thought, "left off" would probably work well for your query.  This would eliminate the serious overhead that you have encountered.  (Bots plagued me about 15 years ago; that led me to caming up with the workaround.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two single column indices on `Product2Section` serve no purpose. You should change your junction table to:

```
CREATE TABLE `Product2Section` (
  `SectionId` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ProductId` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`SectionId`, `ProductId`),
  KEY `idx_ProductId_SectionId` (`ProductId`, `SectionId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

> There are other queries in the system that probably use the single field indexes

The single column indices cannot be used for anything that the two composite indices cannot be used for. They are just wasting space and cause unnecessary overhead on insert and for the optimizer. Setting one of the composite indices as PRIMARY stops [InnoDB from having to create its own internal rowid](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-index-types.html), which just wastes space. It also adds the uniqueness constraint which is currently missing from your table.

From the docs:

> Accessing a row through the clustered index is fast because the index search leads directly to the page that contains the row data. If a table is large, the clustered index architecture often saves a disk I/O operation when compared to storage organizations that store row data using a different page from the index record.

This is not significant for a *"simple"* junction table as both columns should be stored in both indices, therefor no further read is required.

You said:

> that didn't really bother me since there was no real performance hit

You may not see the difference when running an individual query with no contention but the difference in a highly contended production environment can be huge, due to the amount of *effort* required.

Do you really need to accommodate 4,294,967,295 (`int unsigned`) sections? Perhaps the 65,535 provided by `smallint unsigned` would be enough?

You said:

> Might change it in the future. Don't think it will change the performance somehow

Changing SectionId to smallint will reduce each index entry from 8 to 6 bytes. That's a 25% reduction in size. Smaller is faster.

Why are you using `LEFT JOIN`? The fact that you are happy to reverse the order of the tables in the query suggests it should be an `INNER JOIN`.

Do you have your buffer pool configured appropriately, or is it set to defaults? Please run `ANALYZE TABLE Product2Section;` and then provide the output from:

```
SELECT TABLE_ROWS, AVG_ROW_LENGTH, DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH
FROM information_schema.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Product2Section';
```

And:

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM(DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH)/POW(1024, 3), 2)
FROM information_schema.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_database_name';
```

And:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_buffer%';
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252051/discussion-on-answer-by-nnichols-order-by-fields-from-different-tables-create-fu); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.